# terraform - How to Create Route53 for DNS?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform to create AWS resources.
Terraform v0.11.3
provider.aws v1.11.0
provider.template v1.0.0

I want to create Active Directory and I am able to do the same successfully.

Now I am trying to use Route53 instead of ActiveDirectory DNS.Problem is while creating Route53 Zone, SO I have to create SRV records in Route53 which should point towards Active Directory Domain Controllers.

My Problem is that terraform only provide me the IP address of Domain Controller, But it does not tell me about the HOSTNAME of Domain Controllers.
Whereas My A Record needed Hostname of a domain controller.

```
    resource "aws_directory_service_directory" "MyActiveDirectory" {
       name       = "${var.DOMAINNAME}"
       password   = "${var.DOMAINADMINPASSWORD}"
       size       = "${var.DOMAINSIZE}"
       vpc_settings {
       vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.MyVpc.id}"
       subnet_ids = ["${aws_subnet.PvtSubnetA.id}","${aws_subnet.PvtSubnetB.id}"]
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you just make up some hostnames within your domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much set the hostnames to anything you like. For example:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "foo" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.id}"
  name    = "foo"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["${aws_directory_service_directory.MyActiveDirectory.dns_ip_addresses}"]
}
```

Things that auto-discover the domain will use the SRV records, but for then in anything that needs to know the address of the AD server(s) you can just use the `foo` name.